# Is there a way to use the userstore of wso2 identity server which has installed in Microsoft azure using ADFS with oAuth2 service instead of SSO?

Tags: azure, ldap, adfs, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

- I'm trying to intergrate Microsoft Azure with WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0. I have installed the identity server in azure and configured LDAP User Store in wso2 Identity server.
- My requirement is to use that inhouse usertore using ADFS.
- I have found the way of doing this using SSO but is there a way of doing this using oAuth2 service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your users are in LDAP, you can use ADFS in WS 2016 to directly connect them. After that, they can be used via any federation protocol that ADFS 2016 supports which is WS-*, SAML, OAuth, OpenID Connect. You can see how to configure LDAP at https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories.

Thanks
//Sam (Twitter: **@MrADFS**)